# MySQL- List inside of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What I'm trying to is create a table that will keep track of users who report a comment on a website. Right now, I have a table that would look something like this:

```
  id   |  num_reports  |  users  
-----------------------------------
 12345         1
 12489         4
```

For this table, I'd like id to be unique and number_reports to keep incrementing starting at 1. But for users, I'm getting confused because I'd like to keep a record of user_ids who created a report and I'm unsure of how to make it so I can store multiple user_ids.

I thought of doing something like

```
id   |  user_id
---------------
123      567
123      689
```

and in this case, you would just count the number of rows with id being duplicated and user_id being unique, but this just seemed inefficient.

I've been looking around, and it looks like the correct way would be creating another table, but how does that allow me to store multiple user_ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the right way to do it. Here is what you should have:

```
USERS                  COMMENTS
+---------+------+    +------------+---------+------------+---------------------+
| id_user | name |    | id_comment | id_user | id_article | date                |
+---------+------+    +------------+---------+------------+---------------------+
| 171     | Joe  |    | 245        | 245     | 24         | 2015-03-22 10:12:00 |
| 180     | Jack |    | 1245       | 180     | 68         | 2015-03-23 23:01:19 |
| ...     | ...  |    | ...        | ...     | ...        | ...                 |
+---------+------+    +------------+---------+------------+---------------------+

COMMENT_REPORTS
+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| id_report | id_comment | id_user | date                |
+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+
| 1         | 245        | 171     | 2015-03-24 16:11:15 |
| 2         | 654        | 180     | 2015-03-24 18:13:42 |
| 3         | 1245       | 180     | 2015-03-24 18:34:01 |
| 4         | 1245       | 456     | 2015-03-25 09:58:10 |
| ...       | ...        | ...     | ...                 |
+-----------+------------+---------+---------------------+
```

You then will be able to get:

```
# Every reports made by an user
SELECT * 
FROM comment_reports
WHERE user_id = 180

# Every reports related to a comment
SELECT * 
FROM comment_reports
WHERE comment_id = 1245

# Every reports made today
SELECT * 
FROM comment_reports
WHERE date >= CURDATE()

# The amount of reports related to an user's comments
SELECT c.id_user AS User, COUNT(cr.id_report) AS Reported
FROM comment_reports cr
JOIN comments c ON (cr.id_comment = c.id_comment)
WHERE c.id_user = 180
GROUP BY c.id_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you making datawarehouse? Normally quantity of reports for the websites are not saved. They are calculated on the fly by taking COUNT(*) by the website_id from the table where reports are saved. There you can save user who made this report. And then you can play by taking total of reports, or total of reports by user etc.

However if you have solution like that then you have no other option than to create separate link table for storing report<-->user links.

Comment: Depending on the nesting depth and the amount of data i would not count on the fly....

Answer (score 0):

You can find users by there unique id, due to increment, user always unique, and never be overwrite.